# config email yahoo, AOL for codeigniter from the local server

Tags: codeigniter, email, smtp

I  used the following code for yahoo and it did not work, can you help where I am doing wrong. The same code when I used for the gmail with host as smtp.gmail.com it worked well. I am trying to send an email from the local server using yahoo, AOL,  windows hotmail .  The following is a file created in application/config folder with the name email.php

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "myusername@yahoo.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "**************";
$config['smtp_port'] = "465";
$config['charset']="utf-8";
$config['newline']="\r";
$config['crlf'] = "\r";
```

The working code for gmail

```
$config['protocol'] = "smtp";
$config['smtp_host'] = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$config['smtp_user'] = "username@gmail.com";
$config['smtp_pass'] = "*****";
$config['smtp_port'] = '465';
$config['charset']='utf-8';
$config['newline']="\r\n";
$config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo uses port 995 as the outgoing mail port

http://www.emailaddressmanager.com/tips/mail-settings.html

Comment: I have the following error when I tried 995 as port

Message: fsockopen(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.mail.yahoo.com:995 (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: yeah i also got same error for yahoo, for hotmail i am getting another error..........

Comment: @Venkat Yeah I used for gmail with gmail host and it worked well. The settings arent working for yahoo, AOL

Comment: yeah i know i also faced same problems and from morning on wards i tried to help one guy from stack overflow about same problem using Hotmail. He is also facing same problem.

Comment: Try this it might help http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/bizmail/pop/pop-27.html